# 2 Maps with same key. Counting keys

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, maps

So I have two maps. First one (idsandcount) has the id as key and number ordered as count. Second map has id as key and ingredient as value. How do implement a method that gives a list with an arraylist?

```
public static List<Ingredient> ingredientsFromIdAndCount(Map<Long, Integer> idsAndCount, Map<Long, Ingredient> articles) {

    Map<Ingredient, Long> inversedArt = new HashMap<>();
    articles.forEach((key, value) -> inversedArt.put((value), key));

    
    
    List<Ingredient> ingredientList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Ingredient art : articles.values()) ingredientList.add(art);


    return ingredientList;
```

From Test class:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("should get the ingredients from the passed menu in the stated quantities of the input map")
void ingredientsFromIdAndCount() {
    Map<Long, Integer> counts = Map.of(
            66L, 1,
            17L, 2);
```

```
private final Map<Long, Ingredient> testMenu = Map.of(
        42L, gurken,
        66L, kaese,
        17L, fleisch);

        List<Ingredient> expected = List.of(kaese, fleisch, fleisch);
        List<Ingredient> actual = 
        MenuUtils.ingredientsFromIdAndCount(counts, testMenu);
```

I basically want an arraylist of kaese, fleisch, fleisch.

I have tried inversing(don't know if i need it here). My main thought was to get an arraylist of the ids from the first map. An arraylist of 66, 17, 17 to then get the values from the second map using these key. Problem is I just started working with maps and arraylists, so its very confusing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* We will be able to modify the values in this map */
        Map<Long, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
        counts.put(66L, 1);
        counts.put(17L, 2);
        
        /* You cannot modify keys/value of map if it is implemented with Map.of() */
        Map<Long, String> testMenu = Map.of(
                42L, "gurken",
                66L, "kaese",
                17L, "fleisch");
        
        System.out.println("Count Map: " + counts);
        System.out.println("Ingredient Map: " + testMenu + "\n");
        
        List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        
        /* Access both key/value with entrySet() */
        for(Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
            long key = entry.getKey();
            int val = entry.getValue();
            for(int i = 0; i < val; i++) {
                ingredients.add(testMenu.get(key));
            }
            counts.put(key, counts.get(key) - val);
        }
        
        System.out.println("List of ingredients: " + ingredients);
        System.out.println("Updated Count Map: " + counts);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
Count Map: {17=2, 66=1}
Ingredient Map: {17=fleisch, 66=kaese, 42=gurken}

List of ingredients: [fleisch, fleisch, kaese]
Updated Count Map: {17=0, 66=0}
```

Note, keys and values are immutable when you use the Map.of() method.
I used strings instead of your Ingredients class object in the map, but you can modify the code with a little tinkering. If your having an issue, let me know.

Comment: This helped me a lot with progress. However, this gives me the number of keyset once. What i want is have the keyset depending on the amount of value. So when the value is 2, i want that key twice. After researching a little, i found streams to be fitting in this case no? But i couldn't make it work with the way i want it.

`
        idsAndCount.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() < 0L)
                .map(idsAndCount::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
`

can i somehow make it so that the value decreases by 1 every time it filters?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, if you had  [{66L, 1}, {17L, 2}] then you want something like ["kaese", "fleisch", "fleisch"] ? If not, then you need to edit your post with an example and the desired output that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah I want kaese fleisch fleisch as output. But with the implementation above, it only takes fleisch once instead of twice. I am basically trying to find a way to get the Key multiple times depending on the value of the map. Basically 66, 17, 17. And then i can use the second part you helped me with.

Comment: I am currently thinking of adding a condition to the loop that fills listofID. Maybe i can tell something like if value is bigger than 0, get keyset. Wouldn't it loop 66, 17, 17 then? something like this 

`for (Long entry : idsAndCount.keySet()) {
if (idsAndCount.values() > 0) {
listOfId.add(entry);
idsAndCount.values() --;
}}`

Comment: Edited the code above. Is that what you're looking for?